# How to Determine if STDIN is Empty?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm writing an emulator for my Operating Systems course. The problem I have is that we need to get all our .job files (they are like application programs being fed to the emulator) from STDIN and read them in.

Call:

```
./RMMIX < aJob.job
```

I just slurp it with

```
while(getline(std::cin, line))
```

line by line. The problem is, if I do not put anything to STDIN, then cin will wait for user input- NOT what I want. I need the program to recognize a lack of text on STDIN and terminate, not wait for user input instead.

I have determined that I can query the length like so:

```
size_t beg = std::cin.tellg();
std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
size_t end = std::cin.tellg();
std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

and terminate if std::cin has a length of 0.

Are there any other solutions to this? Is this a portable solution?

Comment: I don't think you can without using some system specific code. If cin is connected to a console, the EOF condition is that I will press Ctrl+D/Ctrl+Z as my next input. The system just has to wait until I type something before it can decide!

Comment: Streams don't have lengths. They are flows of information, not containers. Really you're enquiring about the length of the filled portion of `cin`'s read buffer.

Comment: What your code is trying to do is effectively to seek in a pipe, which as far as I know is undefined.

Comment: If you don't redirect anything with `<`, than there **is** something at the standard input. The user input. You'd have to `< /dev/null`. Then there'd be nothing, because `/dev/null` is always empty.

Comment: You **want** it to wait for user input. That's now any and every program expecting data on standard input behaves, so if your differs, you are just going to confuse whoever is going to run it.

Comment: @Hudex: That is a good point. I think I'll go talk to my professor instead of finding a non-portable and ugly workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a platform independent way of doing this, but on Unix-based systems you should be able to do:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...

int main() {
    if (!isatty(0)) {
        // stdin is being streamed from a file or something else that's not a TTY.
    }

    ...
}
```

However, I think doing it via a command line option is the preferred approach.

Comment: This should be `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` or `isatty(fileno(stdin))` and, if the latter, compiled with `-D_POSIX_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redesign your program. Instead of reading from standard input, read from a named file, who's name you provide on the command line. Then instead of:

```
./RMMIX < aJob.job
```

you say:

```
./RMMIX aJob.job
```

This is much easier and more portable than trying to determine if there is anything in standard input.

Comment: @unpersson: This is my preferred way of doing things (praise be to boost::program_options), but you know professors... have to have things the way they want it, not what's better.

Comment: @SoulBeaver I do know professors - I used to be one, and many of us are quite reasonable people. Either explain to him that what he wants can't be done, or ask him to explain how to do it - that's his job, after all!

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  I have no idea what the OP's program does, but this is very un-unix-philosophy-like, and encourages inefficient uses like creating temporary files if this needs to be run in a pipeline (or otherwise complicates the syntax of using this in a script).  To op: chances are your instructor knows and expects that your program will wait for input if invoked without redirection to standard in.  I know this is an old question, but I feel this needs to be said.

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at this http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/CandCPP/232821/232821/non-blocking-reads-on-stdin/ for an idea that comes at the problem from another direction -- don't check the number of bytes on the stream, but instead just make the read succeed immediately and then check to see if anything was read.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Ctrl+D on the command line to signal end-of-file for standard input on the running program.

This is desired behavior.  Otherwise, if programs exited immediately when no input remained, pipelines could randomly be broken by commands that were waiting on another command that had not been scheduled to run (and that had not produced any additional output), or that buffered output and emitted it all at once, like `sort` does.

When using io redirection to pull stdin from a file via something like `./RMMIX < file.txt`, this end-of-file condition is signaled automatically when there is no more data left in the file.  For input read from a terminal, waiting is probably the desired behavior.